# progress bar formula

Tags: formula, formula-field, campaign, image-formula

I am trying to develop a formula that will give me a progress bar with images in the campaigns

The idea that i want to achieve is that I have days from the start of the campaign till the end of the campaign(field **Days_from_Start_to_End_Date__c**). And with those numbers i want to see the progress bar changing.

For example if the StartDate = Today() that means progress bar should point out 0%, If EndDate = Today() that means progress bar should point to 100%.

Now the catchy part is i want somehow the number of days to be divided in 5 so if i have 20 days for all campaign. I want to divide it 20/5.
So the formula should point out something like this.

- from 0 till 4 days 0%
- from 5 days till 8 20%
- from 9 till 12 40%
- from 13 till 16 60%
- from 17 till 20 80%
- 20+ 100%

Here is where i am now with my code.

```
IF( StartDate = Today(), IMAGE("/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=01520000002aVsZ", "0%"),
    IF (  Days_from_Start_to_End_Date__c / 5 + Days_from_Start_to_End_Date__c / 5, IMAGE("/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=01520000002aVxZ", "20%"),
    IF ( Days_from_Start_to_End_Date__c / 5 + Days_from_Start_to_End_Date__c / 5, IMAGE("/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=01520000002aVxe", "40%"),
    IF ( Days_from_Start_to_End_Date__c / 5 + Days_from_Start_to_End_Date__c / 5 + Days_from_Start_to_End_Date__c / 5, IMAGE("/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=01520000002aVxj", "60%"),
    IF ( Days_from_Start_to_End_Date__c / 5 + Days_from_Start_to_End_Date__c / 5 + Days_from_Start_to_End_Date__c / 5 + Days_from_Start_to_End_Date__c / 5, IMAGE("/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=01520000002aVy3", "80%"),
IF ( Days_from_Start_to_End_Date__c / 5 + Days_from_Start_to_End_Date__c / 5 + Days_from_Start_to_End_Date__c / 5 + Days_from_Start_to_End_Date__c / 5 + Days_from_Start_to_End_Date__c / 5, IMAGE("/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=01520000002aVy3", "100%"),
          "ERROR"))))))
```

Also in the code abowe you can see the pat of the different images from 0% till 100%.

I really hope i was clear with the explanation if not please let me know.

Please advise,

Darko

Comment: And which error did you get? Or I mean what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: The problem that i am facing is i can't figure a way out to do this. I've tried everything and I am not able to find a way to make the the formula does what i want. See below

from 0 till 4 days 0%

from 5 days till 8 20%

from 9 till 12 40%

from 13 till 16 60%

from 17 till 20 80%

20+ 100%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just experimented with some fields on my org. The following formula should work.

I use here following fields:

- Start__c
- End__c
- NumDays__c: Formula (End__c - Start__c)
- Today__c: just a Date field for more comfortable testing purpose

The main formula:

```
IF( (((Today__c - Start__c)/ NumDays__c)*100) == 0, IMAGE('/img/samples/stars_000.gif', '0%'), 
(IF((((Today__c - Start__c)/ NumDays__c)*100) > 0 && (((Today__c - Start__c)/ NumDays__c)*100) <= 20,  IMAGE('/img/samples/stars_100.gif', '20%'),
(IF((((Today__c - Start__c)/ NumDays__c)*100) > 20 && (((Today__c - Start__c)/ NumDays__c)*100) <= 40,  IMAGE('/img/samples/stars_200.gif', '40%'),
(IF((((Today__c - Start__c)/ NumDays__c)*100) > 40 && (((Today__c - Start__c)/ NumDays__c)*100) <= 60,  IMAGE('/img/samples/stars_300.gif', '60%'),
(IF((((Today__c - Start__c)/ NumDays__c)*100) > 60 && (((Today__c - Start__c)/ NumDays__c)*100) <= 80,  IMAGE('/img/samples/stars_400.gif', '80%'),
(IF((((Today__c - Start__c)/ NumDays__c)*100) > 80,  IMAGE('/img/samples/stars_500.gif', '100%'),'100%')))))))) )) )
```

And here is a result:

[image]

Comment: Can you please elaborate why you have *100 ? Its confusing a bit.

Thanks

Comment: This is a percent calculation to get a human friendly percent digit like 25 and not 0.25

Comment: It does not support width percentage anymore. The format of IMAGE is IMAGE(image_url, alternate_text, height, width) currently.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should do the trick:

> IF(
>
> (TODAY()-StartDate)/(EndDate-StartDate) < 0.2, IMAGE1,
>
> IF((TODAY()-StartDate)/(EndDate-StartDate) < 0.4, IMAGE2,
>
> IF((TODAY()-StartDate)/(EndDate-StartDate) < 0.6, IMAGE3,
>
> IF((TODAY()-StartDate)/(EndDate-StartDate) < 0.8, IMAGE4, IMAGE5)
>
> )))

You probably also want to capture the situation when TODAY() < StartDate or TODAY() > EndDate, but this should get you started.